# Is a university that grants me a PhD for $1000 and a copy of my unpublished book fake?

Tags: phd, university, degree, accreditation

I have paid $1000 for PhD in mathematics. And I have sent them my book to be considered as a PhD thesis.

Now I suspect that I have lost the money.

But as far as I know they are not accredited by the U.S. Department of Education.

So, is it possible that I will find a job requiring a degree, using this (fake?) PhD?

Now they have told me that the U.S. Department of Education will send my diploma to US foreign affairs department and then they will make some "stumps" on my diploma. Do these stamps mean anything? Are these stamps just a formal thing which mean nothing and don't make my degree "official" ("real")? Moreover, to send my diploma to the departments costs additional $1000-$1750 (dependent on whether I pay right now or later).

Comment: http://consumerwatchdogbw.blogspot.com/2013/06/and-another-fake-university-grant-town.html

Comment: @ff524: I have already read this blog post earlier. It does NOT convince me that GTU is fake, because it says just that they give life-experience degrees (not only degrees based on study in their university)

Comment: At best, this sounds like you've paid $1000 for a worthless piece of paper. At worst, this sounds like a scam. No credible university would do this, and listing such a "degree" could even be _damaging_ to your CV. A "life experience degree" *is not* a University degree.

Comment: I have removed the name of the university, because we generally do not answer questions about specific universities; see the [help/on-topic]

Comment: Life-experience degree sounds like a euphemism for "you were duped."

Comment: @porton what kind of evidence *would* convince you that this university is "fake" (or not)?

Comment: I would not waste any money on a degree that is not conferred by an accredited institution.  You can find accredited (US) schools at the following government site:  http://ope.ed.gov/accreditation/

Comment: @porton "give life-experience degrees" is the same as "fake". No, this degree (should you ever receive it) will not help you in the slightest when applying for jobs requiring a PhD. I am sorry, but you have certainly been scammed.

Comment: I am having trouble believing anyone would actually pay for this.

Comment: To put it simply: Any PhD degree that you can get by paying and without spending considerable time and effort doing research will probably be either fake or useless. There are no shortcuts.

Comment: @Marc: Scams which no one falls for don't exist for very long.  This particular OP has been trying to do "independent mathematical research" for several years now.  I find the news that he has been exploited in this way truly heartbreaking.  I think that mainstream academics should have more sympathy for people like this -- there is **absolutely nothing wrong with wanting to be a mathematician**.  For some people wanting to be a mathematician is a very unrealistic goal, but that does not mean that they deserve to be cheated!

Comment: @user2379888 , for porton's sake, I hope so.  However, it sounds real enough not to be discounted.  Even if the whole thing is fictional, it serves as a cautionary tale, as well as an opportunity for "the other side" to come clean about their practices.

Comment: @user2379888, Marc: As I've mentioned, I got emails about scams like this 15-20 years ago (at my university email address, no less!). There's clearly enough victims to keep it going.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I am not reveling in the fact the OP got scammed and I genuinely do agree that the basic ambition shown here is a very good thing to have. That said, I am having trouble sympathizing in these circumstances because I consider trying to buy a degree to be a form of cheating as well. To me, such attempts are on an equal level of moral wrongs as cheating exams, if not worse.

Comment: @Marc: The document submitted by the OP is longer than most PhD theses in mathematics.  The OP has been working on and trying to publish it for several years: longer than many PhD students spend working on their thesis.  Content issues aside, I believe is 100% sincere.  Further, there is nothing inherently immoral about paying money in pursuit of an academic degree: many of us would be out of a job if that were the case.  Characterizing the OP's behavior as cheating seems to miss many of the heartbreaking nuances of the situation.  I hope you'll reconsider your lack of sympathy.

Comment: @Pete L. Clark "I would share your opinion if not for these lines. Albert: I already have the thesis, it is a 300 pages book ... how long will it take you to review my thesis?
Senior Guy: Well it will take us 24 Hours." Anybody who can go for the offer after *this* either has no idea what mathematics is, or....

Comment: @fedja: I believe that that quote was from when another user on this site investigated the matter, and I don't think there is any reason to believe that the original poster had received any similar information.

Comment: @fedja Thomas is correct, I will clarify it in the answer.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark If he really wants to be a mathematician and has done considerable work in mathematics alone, should he approach a Prof, who may be able to help him. I am a PhD student myself and I think Profs are quite supportive in such cases. What do you think? (I am tagging you since you said that "there is nothing wrong with wanting to be a mathematician" and I see that you are a Prof too :) )

Comment: OP: did you pay with a credit card? You might have recourse if so.

Comment: @JohnJohnson: Yes, I've paid with VISA. How to get money back?

Comment: @porton Call VISA and tell them what happened, that the seller is dishonest, and you want a refund.

Comment: @porton how did this turn out? Were you able to get a refund?

Comment: @porton So did you get a refund or chargeback? Sounds like possible fraud, depending on what representations they made on website or email.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: I have to agree with Marc. Your statements are correct, but "there is nothing inherently immoral about paying money in pursuit of an academic degree" simplifies things too much in my opinion: There is indeed nothing inherently immoral about paying money when that is an administrative/organisational requirement to *get a chance to obtain a PhD based on one's research success*. However, paying money *in exchange for a guaranteed degree* is a whole different story, and at least if the OP was aware that research requirements are replaced by a payment (and maybe some superficial ...

Comment: ... formal requirements, such as hand in a 150+ pages document that looks like it's professional at first glance), cheating is the right term.

Comment: @O.R. Mapper: I agree with everything you say.  In this case, I firmly believe that the OP did not believe that research requirements were being replaced by payment.  As I've said, he's spent many years pursuing mathematical research and has some published papers in generals that academic professionals would regard as predatory.  I really don't think he is trying to cheat or take advantage of anyone.

Comment: There was a [New York Times article](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/05/18/world/asia/fake-diplomas-real-cash-pakistani-company-axact-reaps-millions-columbiana-barkley.html) this summer exposing the company that sells degrees through GTU and other "universities."

Comment: @MarcClaesen Most people in most country's at one point or another pay large sums for their degree. There are several legit degrees that can be earned based on submitted publications, thesis and so on and does not require attending a school. If someone is not familiar with the system, may believe that such an offer is a legit offer, so your comment is too harsh.

Answer (score 96):

**You have lost the money whether or not the "university" gives you the degree.**

You have given your money to what is known as a *diploma mill.* A long time ago (nearly two decades!), I received an email offering degrees from "prestigious, non-accredited universities" based on life experience. This is a complete and total scam. *Even if* you have a diploma, it will be useless for professional purposes. Anybody responsible for hiring a PhD will see that there is no work resulting from your "graduate career," which will be a tipoff that the degree is worthless, and you will be unlikely to receive a job offer. Worse still, even if you were to get an offer, it could be rescinded when the truth is uncovered.

Disengage now, before you lose any further money on this situation.

*Addendum*: I should also mention that I am unaware of the US Department of Education doing *any* certification of diplomas and certificates on an *individual* basis.

Comment: I believe the "stamps" he refers to is notarization of the signature on the diploma ([see "apostille"](http://www.granttownuniversity.com/sample-documents/))

Comment: @ff524: Maybe so. But that would in any case not be the US Department of Education.

Comment: More significantly, notarization of the signature on the diploma doesn't signify anything about the degree the diploma is supposed to reflect

Comment: Wikipedia has a list of animals with degrees from diploma mills: [List of animals with fraudulent diplomas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animals_with_fraudulent_diplomas)

Comment: I don't see why this 'university' won't send him a piece of paper with degree and his name on it. This would help them avoid being sued.

Comment: @QuoraFeans: What I meant is that even if the university sends the degree, the money is "lost" in that the degree is worthless. (And given that it doesn't appear to be a US outfit, good luck suing them.)

Comment: I'll give you a nice looking full color diploma for only $295.99, plus only 1 hour turnaround after receiving your thesis... BTW, my cat constantly receives credit card offers from CitiBank; perhaps I should get her a degree first?

Comment: I know this thread is old news by now, but it bears repeating because diploma mills are a real threat: The US Department of Education does not accredit institutions of higher education. That means that the idea that a certain degree is accredited by the US government is absolutely bunk, false.

Comment: I have just learned what he was referring to w.r.t. "stamps from the US foreign affairs": http://www.nytimes.com/2015/05/18/world/asia/fake-diplomas-real-cash-pakistani-company-axact-reaps-millions-columbiana-barkley.html ("Such certificates, which help a degree to be recognized abroad..")

Answer (score 69):

In case there was any doubt, I have asked them. This is the conversation I had with them (some irrelevant parts omitted):

> **Albert:** Hello, I have written a book on Mathematics that I would like to turn into a PhD thesis
>   **Albert:** what do I have to do?
>   **Their Guy:** What is your highest level of education?
>   **Albert:** I have a Masters degree in mathematics
>   **Their Guy:** Ph.D degree will cost you $1100.00 (USD)
>   **Their Guy:**
>   • 1 Original Accredited Degree
>   • 2 Original Transcripts
>   • 1 Award of Excellence
>   • 1 Certificate of Distinction
>   • 1 Certificate of Membership
>   • 4 Education Verification Letters
>   **Albert:** how long will it take to complete it?
>   **Albert:** I already have the thesis, it is a 300 pages book
>   **Their Guy:** When are you planning to enroll?
>   **Albert:** as soon as possible
>   **Albert:** once the payment and the thesis are sent, how long will it take to have it accepted?
>   **Senior Guy:** Alright you have been transferred to senior student counselor
>   **Senior Guy:** Shipment Details :-
>   **Senior Guy:** 2 set of documents we are going to send you in total in 2 separate shipments.
>   -First set of degree documents will be sent in just 15 - 20 working days with all 10 degree documents without attestations.
>   -Second set of documents will be sent in only 25 - 30 working days with complete and comprehensive attestations with all above mentioned authorities.
>   **Senior Guy:** Total Fee Submission including all registrations would be $1700.00 USD ( $1100 + $600 )
>   **Albert:** how long will it take you to review my thesis?
>   **Senior Guy:** Well it will take us 24 Hours
>   **Senior Guy:** Forward your resume & thesis on sguy@paymeuniversity.com
>   **Albert:** thank you, you have been most enlightening

So, they are reviewing 300 pages in 24 h (where it should take like a year). They do no checking whatsoever on what I would be submitting.

I am sorry, but you have lost the money.

***Edit:***

I have found something funny. [The faculty](http://www.granttownuniversity.com/about/visiting-faculty/) (only visiting faculty seems visible for our university) is the same as, including pictures and order, in [another online university](http://www.hilluniversity.com/our-faculty/) and [another one](http://www.riverbanksuniversity.com/our-faculty/) and [another](http://www.wacuniversity.com/our-faculty/) and [yet another one](http://www.pittsforduniversity.com/our-faculty/), [¡and](http://headwayuniversity.com/our-faculty/) even [more!](http://www.olwauniversity.com/our-faculty/) (and at least, 5 more, but you get the point); all of them looking equally suspicious.

Comment: A thesis shouldn't take a year to review!

Comment: @aeismail Perhaps not but it cannot be done in a day either.

Comment: Thank you for this public service.  Even if it is fictional (and I hope all the names you used above are), it sounds plausible.  I am certainly not going to pursue such a degree based on this scenario.

Comment: @aeismail review the correctness of a 300 pages maths document takes a while. In practice, they are based on articles and one may assume they are correct.

Comment: @NotQuiteAnOutsider my name is not Albert, nor my phone number is 555555555, and I don't work on Mathematics. Their part is true.

Comment: @aeismail: It depends on what you mean by "reviewing the thesis".  If you mean that a committee member gets a lot less than one year to sit with a thesis before the defense: yes, I have sometimes been given less than three weeks.  However, paperwork aside the vast majority of the reviewing is done by the thesis advisor.  If you count the amount of time the advisor spends discussing and vetting the work with the student: less than a year is not impossible but would be very, very fast.  Anyway, this is probably not the point...

Comment: @Davidmh , indeed.  I am worried about the other names appearing as real, especially in these days of web indexing.  I might recommend Representative and Senior Representative.  In any case, the example is instructive, and names should be changed to not embarrass the guilty here.

Comment: @NotQuiteAnOutsider I see your point, and it is a good one. Changed now.

Comment: Boy, they found some unreasonably fresh-faced and perky visiting professors to clone, didn't they?

Comment: The faculty pics are pretty obviously stock photos.

Comment: … as can easily be determined using Google image search.

Comment: It's not just the same photos, though -- it's also the same names, in the same order.  Either this is one outfit half-assedly pretending to be a bunch of schools, or there's a "scam university" template being passed around.  :P  It certainly doesn't help their case that i can't find a physical address on *any* of them.

Comment: @cHao if you look at their Terms of Service page it's obvious that they use the same document for every site. What's sad is that their search and replace for the university name has an extra space on the end. Example [Hill University's](http://www.hilluniversity.com/policy/tos.asp) where every use of `Hill University` is missing the space between `university` and whatever word is to follow.